# This robot has a joint named "foo" which is not in the gazebo model

Tags: ros, urdf, gazebo-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know this question exists already but it doesn't help.
I want to spawn a robot from urdf using the gazebo_ros package.
I noticed that this happens whenever I define a link in my urdf with no additional parameters.
for example in my case:

> This robot has a joint named
> "pusher_joint" which is not in the
> gazebo model.

Where

```
<link name="pusher_base"/>

  <joint name="base_to_pusher" type="fixed">
      <parent link="base_link"/>
      <child link="pusher_base"/>
      <origin xyz="0.74 -1.058 0.18" rpy="0.000 -0.000 ${pi -1.045}"/> 
  </joint>

 <joint name="pusher_joint" type="prismatic">
     <axis xyz="-1 0 0" />
      <limit effort="20" velocity="10"  lower="0" upper="1.5"/>
      <parent link="pusher_base"/>
      <child link="pusher_end_effector"/>
      <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  </joint>
```

How can I fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208093/this-robot-has-a-joint-named-%22foo%22-which-is-not-in-the-gazebo-model./) by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on ROS Answers with karma: 3339 on 2015-04-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Gazebo doesn't handle links without physical properties.
You need to add the inertial tag (inertia and mass) for Gazebo to recognize it as a "simulable link"
If you don't care about the physics you can give dummy values, that's what I do [here](https://github.com/ros-naoqi/nao_robot/blob/master/nao_description/urdf/naoV40_generated_urdf/nao_fingers.xacro#L7) because I don't know any of the physics of these links.

Hope this helps,

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2015-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2015-04-30**:
So except base_link all other links have to have an explicitly defined inertia?

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2015-04-30**:
yes all the ones who are part of a kinematic chain ( so only the physics link, not the sensor links)